# Show sign up navigation item (anonymous user) and hide (authenticated user) in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal and I am building my first site as an assignment. I'm stuck with the sign up button in the navigation menu. It shows up when a user is logged in and is hidden when a user is not logged in. It really should be the other way around. I can't find the problem. What am I missing here?

Here is a picture of the menu item that should be hidden when logged in:

[image: Sign up button]

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I'm about to suggest a module for this, but there really appears to be no other, easy way to get the behaviour you're looking for.  There is a similar question floating around on Drupal's Stack Exchange page at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197538/drupal-8-register-link

Before I found the above link, I looked for the option on one of our installs, and then, not having found it, I searched the web for a solution. The first result I found was for the module that a user mentions in the above link. The module is [over here](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_link).

Comment: @IanMartens Have you managed to implement a solution to this problem?